# What is the right way to unit test asynchronous functions in NodeJS using Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I need an extremely simple example on how to test function like this:

```
// Read from Redis DB
Main.prototype.readFromRedis = function(key, callback){
    dbClient.get(key, function(err, reply) {
        return callback(err, reply)
    });
}
```

or this:

```
// Write to file
Main.prototype.writeToFile = function(fileName, content, callback){
    fs.appendFile(fileName, content, encoding='utf8', function (err) {
        return callback(err);
    });
}
```

I've been searching for the optimal solution for quite a while but wasn't able to find anything very useful.

My attempts:

```
describe('main', function() {
  it('readFromRedis(key, callback) should read value from DB', function() {
    var main = new Main();
    var error;
    main.readFromRedis('count',function(err){
        err = error;
        });
    expect(error).to.equal(undefined);
  });
});
```

However here the `expect()` executes before the `readFromRedis` besides that I don't find my solution to be the right one.

Comment: Have you seen the [async code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) section in the mocha docs? You can use `done` in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha has support for aync functions ([docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)). You can use `done` to signal the end of the test. Like this:

```
describe('main', function() {
  // accept done as a parameter in the it callback
  it('readFromRedis(key, callback) should read value from DB', function(done) {
    var main = new Main();
    main.readFromRedis('count',function(err){
        expect(error).to.equal(undefined);
        // call done() when the async function has finished
        done()
    });
  });
});
```

When you pass `done` as a parameter into the `it` callback, then the test won't complete until `done` has ben called, or the [timeout](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) has been reached.